# How to determine which version of Oracle Client is being used from the server

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Using Oracle 10g.   ( 10.2.0.4 )

Possibly by looking at either logs or system tables is there a way to determine which version of the oracle client each connection is using.

Our systems initially had 8.1.7 Clients, and then 9.X clients.

We attempted to manually locate all machines that had older clients and upgrade them to  to 10.2 Clients.

We are seeking a method to audit (from the server) if we were successful in upgrading all of our client machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search revealed the following:

- [Oracle Forums thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=621105)
- [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171643/whats-the-best-way-to-determine-which-version-of-oracle-client-im-running)
- [OraFAQ thread](http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/121064/0/)
- [Blog post](http://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2010/08/06/determine-the-oracle-client-release-version-remotely/)

Comment: The first 3 are for client side only  not server side.   The last one is client side but builds a reporting mechanism to report it to a server.

Comment: I also asked this question to "Ask Tom" and he replied there was no way he knew of doing this.   I am going to accept this answer because of the "Blog Post" link as it attempts to report this to the server.  And it has given me the idea to build this functionality into our application.