# How to check Oracle Client installed or not as prerequisite for component installtion

Tags: c#, windows, oracle, installation

I am creating installation package for our component. One of the Pr-requisites is oracle client with minimum version 8i should be installed in the target machine. How can i do this?

i referred below post

> [What's the best way to determine which version of Oracle client I'm running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171643/whats-the-best-way-to-determine-which-version-of-oracle-client-im-running)

by having this i wrote the below action. I tried to check with tnsping utility.

```
string result = string.Empty;
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proces = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("tnsping.exe");
                proces.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                proces.CreateNoWindow = true;
                proces.UseShellExecute = false;
                System.Diagnostics.Process bufor;
                bufor = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proces);
                System.IO.StreamReader Output = bufor.StandardOutput;
                bufor.WaitForExit(2000);
                if (bufor.HasExited)
                {
                    result = Output.ReadToEnd();
                    result = result.ToLower();
                    if (result.Contains("64-bit"))
                    {
                        is64BitOracleClient = true;
                    }

                    int verINT = result.IndexOf("version", 0, result.Length);
                    if (verINT != null)
                    {
                        version = result.Substring(verINT + "version".Length + 1, 8);
                        Version installedVersion = new Version(version);
                        Version expectedVersion = new Version("8.1.7.0");
                        if (installedVersion >= expectedVersion)
                        {
                            isVersionMatched = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

here i am executing tool tnsping. if i receive exception at

```
bufor = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proces);
```

I concluded that Oracle Client is not installed.

If this tool is available, i am getting below result

```
TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 16-AUG-2
012 06:27:58
```

from this result, I am parsing version and validating the same.

Is this right approach? Any other better approach is there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a better answer for you, but I'm using your solution in my application and it is working as expected.