# Check oracle client installed in the local machine

Tags: c#, winforms, oracleclient

We have a C# winforms application running in .Net 2.0. In this application we want to enable some options by checking whether any Oracle client is installed in the local machine.

After googling i found some suggestions like try to start the process "tnsping.exe". While starting the application if it throws some exception means Oracle client is not installed in that machine. I got this information from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984124/how-to-check-oracle-client-installed-or-not-as-prerequisite-for-component-instal) SO post.
But I think in this case it will start the client application.

So i want a way to check Oracle client is installed in the local machine without starting the client application. I am not aware of this oracle installation and all. Can someone help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Is your application going to use the Oracle database ? you need to only check if the oracle client is installed and you will not use oracle database through your app ?

Comment: @AccessDenied : I am not using Oracle database in my application. I just want to check oracle client is installed in that machine.