# How to know installed Oracle Client is 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: oracle, 64-bit, oracleclient

OS: Windows 2008 Server R2

Oracle Client: 11.2

Many Thanks

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1076026

Comment: thanks. but i can find both HKLM>Software>WOW6432Node>Oracle and  HKLM>Software>Oracle in register

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A simple way to find this out in Windows is to run SQLPlus from your Oracle homes's bin directory and then check Task Manager. If it is a 32-bit version of SQLPlus, you'll see a process on the Processes tab that looks like this:

```
sqlplus.exe *32
```

If it is 64-bit, the process will look like this:

```
sqlplus.exe
```

Comment: does the same hold true for windows server 2012? I see it running in task manager as sqlplus.exe, and description is "Oracle SQL*PLUS".

Comment: This method only works with Task Manager. If you use Process Explorer it shows sqlplus.exe for a 32 bit client, however you can display the Image Type column, and this will indicate 64 or 32 bits.

Comment: Good advice. Although task manager wouldn't show "sqlplus.exe *32" on a 32-bit OS, it would be just "sqlplus.exe" ;)

Comment: @n00b For server 2012, "(32 bit)" would be shown after the application name. In your case, it is 64bit.

Comment: I couldnt see this '*32' part in WIndows 10 Task Manager. I went into Task Manager area and right-clicked on the table area there. and selected 'Select Columns' and choose 'Platform' and that seemed to display whether it is a 64 or 32 bit prog

Answer (score 45):

Go to `%ORACLE_HOME%\inventory\ContentsXML` folder and open 
`comps.xml` file

Look for <DEP_LIST> on ~second screen.
If following lines have

`PLAT="NT_AMD64"` then this Oracle Home is 64 bit.

`PLAT="NT_X86"` then - 32 bit.

You may have both 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle Homes installed.

Comment: Useful if you have more than 1 Oracle client!

Comment: This helped me to look for the list.
I've now got another question on this: How do I determine which is a client/something else?

"oracle.sysman.agent" VER="11.1.0.1.0" PLAT="NT_AMD64"
"oracle.sysman.agent.gc" VER="11.1.0.1.0" PLAT="NT_AMD64" 
"oracle.rdbms.install.common" VER="10.2.0.1.0" PLAT="NT_AMD64"
"oracle.swd.oui" VER="10.2.0.1.0" PLAT="NT_AMD64" /> 
"oracle.bali.share" VER="11.1.1.2.0" PLAT="NT_AMD64"
"oracle.sysman.plugin.ai.main.agent" VER="11.1.0.2.0" PLAT="NT_AMD64" 
"oracle.dms" VER="10.1.2.1.0" PLAT="NT_AMD64" 

NOTE: I'm green on this matter.

Comment: @geynske006 not sure if I am in time for this - but since they are all AMD64, you should be fine, just means you have 32-bit across the board.

Answer (score 13):

One thing that was super easy and worked well for me was doing a TNSPing from a cmd prompt:

```
TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on 13-MAR-2015 16:35:32
```

Comment: Mark, I think the "32-bit" you relates to Windows, not Oracle's client

Comment: Nope. I have Windows 8 on my PC and have both 32-bit and 64-bit clients installed due to job requirements.

Comment: @MarkBowytz, but how do you know if you have both 32-bit and 64-bit?

Answer (score 7):

In Linux:

1) find where is sqlplus located,

```
[oracle@LINUX db_1]$ `which sqlplus`
/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/sqlplus
```

2) Determine the file type,

[oracle@LINUX db_1]$  `file /app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/sqlplus`

/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/bin/sqlplus: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs). For GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped.

Answer (score 5):

None of the links above about lib and lib32 folder worked for me with Oracle Client 11.2.0 But I found this on the [OTN community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1078026):

> As far as inspecting a client install to try to tell if it's 32 bit or
>   64 bit, you can check the registry, a 32 bit home will be located in
>   HKLM>Software>WOW6432Node>Oracle, whereas a 64 bit home will be in
>   HKLM>Software>Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

The following, taken from [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_client_32_bit_or_64_bit.htm), was not mentioned here:

> If the Oracle Client is 32 bit, it will contain a "lib" folder; but if it is a 64 bit Oracle Client it will have both "lib" and "lib32" folders.
>
> Also, starting in Oracle 11.2.0.1, the client version for 64-bit and the Oracle client for 32-bit are shipped separately, and there is an $ORACLE_HOME/lib64 directory.
>
> $ORACLE_HOME/lib/     ==> 32 bit
>   $ORACLE_HOME/lib64 ==>  64 bit
>
> Or
>
> $ORACLE_HOME/lib/     ==> 64 bit
>   $ORACLE_HOME/lib32  ==> 32 bit

Answer (score 2):

For the Oracle 12.1 windows client, looking at the output from the TNSPING command seems to work:

With 32 bit installed on 64 bit OS:

> C:>tnsping
>
> TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
>   on 02-FEB-2 016 15:44:37
>
> Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

With 64 bit installed on 64 bit OS:

> D:>tnsping
>
> TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
>   on 02-FEB-2 016 16:00:23
>
> Copyright (c) 1997, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Answer (score 2):

For Unix

```
grep "ARCHITECTURE" $ORACLE_HOME/inventory/ContentsXML/oraclehomeproperties.xml
```

And the output is:

```
<PROPERTY NAME="ARCHITECTURE" VAL="64"/>
```

For Windows

```
findstr "ARCHITECTURE" %ORACLE_HOME%\inventory\ContentsXML\oraclehomeproperties.xml
```

And the output can be:

```
<PROPERTY NAME="ARCHITECTURE" VAL="64"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

On 64-bit system:

32-bit Driver: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

64-bit Driver: `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe`

Go to Drivers Tab
Version is shown there as well.

Answer (score -1):

Only just use the command below...

```
tnsping
```

in administrative powershell. More detail is...

```
  PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> tnsping

  TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 07-DEC-2023 11:18:08

  Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
```